# Student Loan Forgiveness for Web Developers

Tags: united-states, student-loan

I am exploring options for student loan forgiveness. I currently work full-time as a web developer at a corporation. I understand, however, that most SLF plans are only accessible to the public service realm. Are there any SLF options for web developers working in non-public servant capacities? Feedback and recommendations are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To the close voter: This is not a “product or service recommendation” question. It is asking about specific government programs.

Answer (score 7):

The program you are thinking of, [Public Service Loan Forgiveness](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/forgiveness-cancellation/public-service), is only available to people employed by government or non-profit employers. It still requires 10 years of payments.

The standard student loan repayment plan structures your repayment so that your loan will be paid off after 10 years. If you are on this repayment plan, the PSLF would be of no benefit to you even if you were eligible, because at the end of 10 years you will have no loan balance to forgive.

There are [other repayment plans](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/understand/plans) besides the standard repayment plan. Some of these are income-driven payment plans, which base your monthly payment amount on your income. With these income-driven plans, your remaining balance is forgiven after 20-25 years of making payments on the plan. You can be eligible for these plans no matter who your employer is, as long as your income is low enough.

I don’t know how much student loan debt you have or what your income is, but for most people, the best way to handle it is to simply buckle down and attack the debt, paying it off as fast as you can. You do not want to be stuck making student loan payments 15 or 20 years from now. It will be better for you financially to pay it off quickly, which will reduce the total interest that you will pay. In order to try to qualify for one of these balance forgiveness scenarios, you would need to keep your income low for the next 20 years, which would be a disastrous decision to make financially.

---

For completeness, in addition to the PSLF and the income-driven repayment plans, there are [other student loan forgiveness programs](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/forgiveness-cancellation) that forgive debt under specific circumstances, such as death, disability, or problems with the school you attended.